# How to improve MySQL "fill the gaps" query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with currency exchange rates that I fill with data published by the ECB. That data contains gaps in the date dimension like e.g. holidays.

```
CREATE TABLE `imp_exchangerate` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rate_date` date NOT NULL,
  `currency` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `rate` decimal(14,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `rate_date` (`rate_date`,`currency`),
  KEY `imp_exchangerate_by_currency` (`currency`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I also have a date dimension as youd expect in a data warehouse:

```
CREATE TABLE `d_date` (
  `date_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `full_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  ---- etc.
  PRIMARY KEY (`date_id`),
  KEY `full_date` (`full_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Now I try to fill the gaps in the exchangerates like this:

```
SELECT 
  d.full_date,
  currency,
  (SELECT rate FROM imp_exchangerate
   WHERE rate_date <= d.full_date AND currency = c.currency
   ORDER BY rate_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS rate
FROM
  d_date d,
  (SELECT DISTINCT currency FROM imp_exchangerate) c
WHERE
  d.full_date >=
    (SELECT min(rate_date) FROM imp_exchangerate
     WHERE currency = c.currency) AND
  d.full_date <= curdate()
```

Explain says:

```
+------+--------------------+------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type        | table            | type  | possible_keys                          | key                          | key_len | ref        | rows | Extra                                                        |
+------+--------------------+------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | <derived3>       | ALL   | NULL                                   | NULL                         | NULL    | NULL       |  201 |                                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | d                | range | full_date                              | full_date                    | 4       | NULL       | 6047 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | imp_exchangerate | ref   | imp_exchangerate_by_currency           | imp_exchangerate_by_currency | 3       | c.currency |  664 |                                                              |
|    3 | DERIVED            | imp_exchangerate | range | NULL                                   | imp_exchangerate_by_currency | 3       | NULL       |  201 | Using index for group-by                                     |
|    2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | imp_exchangerate | index | rate_date,imp_exchangerate_by_currency | rate_date                    | 6       | NULL       |    1 | Using where                                                  |
+------+--------------------+------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

MySQL needs multiple hours to execute that query. Are there any Ideas how to improve that? I have tried with an index on rate without any noticable impact.

Comment: Can you have multiple exchangerate records for a given currency and date?

Comment: Not really. I need exactly one rate per day and currency. It should either be the rate, the ECB provides for that day, or the last available before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for a while now: get rid of dependent subqueries. I had to think from different angles in mutliple places and here is the result:

```
SELECT
  cd.date_id,
  x.currency,
  x.rate
FROM
  imp_exchangerate x INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT
    d.date_id,
    max(rate_date) as rate_date,
    currency
  FROM
    d_date d INNER JOIN
    imp_exchangerate ON rate_date <= d.full_date
  WHERE
    d.full_date <= curdate()
  GROUP BY
    d.date_id,
    currency) cd ON x.rate_date = cd.rate_date and x.currency = cd.currency
```

This query finishes in  less then 10 minutes now compared to multiple hours for the original query.

Lesson learned: avoid dependent subqueries in MySQL like the plague!